# How to kill a process created by Python subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to call a DOS .exe file from Python and delete this .exe after the computation. I am able to call it using `subprocess.Popen` and `os.system`, however, I could not delete this .exe file if it is called by `subprocess.Popen`. The error is `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`. Can anyone let me know how to kill this process?
Thanks!

`subprocess` approach (does not work):

```
a = subprocess.Popen("dos.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(5)
a.kill()
os.remove("dos.exe")

# gets error msg "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied"
```

`os.system` approach (works):

```
a=os.system("dos.exe")
os.remove("dos.exe")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wait for the process to complete before deleting the .exe. Call a.communicate() or a.wait() before deleting the .exe